# 'TypeError: is not a function' instance method in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Account.getAccount is not a function ...

When I call an instance method from a class I created. Other scripts with the same imports can call the constructor or instance fields with no issue, so I don't know why the instance methods are failing. I have looked through all the documentation but cannot figure out the problem. This is running on replit.

This file `account.js` contains the class Account and two instance methods, `getAccount` and `payAccount`.

```
class Account {
  static lastId = 1001;
  static generateId() {
    return Account.lastId++;
  }
  static accounts = [1000];
  static names = [];
  static ids = [];
  profile;
  ign;
  balance;
  id;
  constructor(ign, profile) {
    this.ign = ign;
    this.profile = profile;
    this.balance = 0;
    this.id = Account.generateId();
    Account.accounts.push(this);
    Account.names.push(ign);
    Account.ids.push(this.id);
  }
  getAccount(id) { // this is the instance method that is called later.
    for (const element of accounts) {
      if (id == element.id) return element;
    }
    return;
  }
  payAccount(account, amount) {
    account.balance += amount;
  }
}
module.exports = Account;
```

Here are snippets from another file pay.js (full path commands/pay.js):

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const Account = require('../Account') // it is in a folder, hence the '../'
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('pay')
    .setDescription('Description')
    .addIntegerOption(fromAccount =>
      fromAccount.setName('from_account')
        .setDescription('One of your Accounts.')
        .setRequired(true)),
async execute(interaction) {
    let fromId = interaction.options.getInteger('from_account');
    let fromAccount = Account.getAccount(fromId); // the error is thrown here
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have seen similar questions about plain functions but the syntax is different with classes.
(Also please ignore having so many static arrays I was just trying to get around using the instance methods.)

Comment: Its not supposed to be a instance method if used without an instance.

Comment: @tkausl would it work if I declared the methods outside of the class? I am trying but I cannot figure out how without changing them to generic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate an `Account` instance to call a method of the class:

```
async execute(interaction) {
    let fromId = interaction.options.getInteger('from_account');
    const account = new Account(<ign>, <profile>);
    let fromAccount = account.getAccount(fromId);
  }
```

Or, declare the method as `static`:

```
static getAccount(id) { // this is the instance method that is called later.
    for (const element of accounts) {
      if (id == element.id) return element;
    }
    return;
}

...

let fromAccount = Account.getAccount(fromId); // will work
```

Finally, you can change your `getAccount` implementation to:

```
static getAccount(id) { 
    return Account.accounts.find(a => a.id === id);
}
```